# Is there a way to splitscreen Metro apps in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

Is there a way to show two Metro apps (the kind you launch by clicking on a tile) at a time in Windows 8 as opposed to filling up the entire display every time you launch one?

Comment: Please clarify if you're talking about Metro apps or classic apps running on the desktop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in the same way as regular Windows applications.

1. The possible view states for an application are [image]
   source: http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-Metro-Layout-view-states-and-navigation.aspx
2. You can split them in side by side mode

> **Let’s see how split screen is enabled for a Metro app in Windows 8.**
>
> 1.You need to open the Metro Start Screen and open your app e.g the Finance App.
>
> 2.Left click on the App and hold your mouse button. You will see the app appears in a small window.
>
> 3.Drag the app in the small window on either end of the screen horizontally.
>
> 4.Open the Metro Screen again and click Desktop.
>
> 5.You will now see the Finance App and Desktop simultaneously showing on the screen.

source http://www.technize.net/how-to-run-metro-apps-in-split-screen-in-windows-8/

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial alternative, but works well in certain scenarios, particularly when you want to have browser windows side-by-side.

There's a new app called [Toolbox for Windows 8](http://apps.microsoft.com/webpdp/en-us/app/toolbox-for-windows-8/70e5e6af-017c-47e4-923b-db71bd9110ba) that offers many different "snapped" views within its own app. It has its own nine "tools" built-in, including a browser:

[image: Web browser, Calculator, Unit converter, Facebook, Voice notes, Notifier, Clock, Weather, Doodles]

These tools can be arranged in a variety of pre-defined snapped layouts, and can be put together into custom layouts as well. One of the options is a split side-by-side view, which is useful for viewing two webpages at once, for example:

[image]

You can also put together multiple tools into custom configurations:

[image]

And you can even split tools while snapping the whole app to one side, letting you snap within your snaps. Yo, dawg!

[image]

Obviously this won't work for *all* situations, but I've found it to be a very useful tool (no pun intended) for situations where the default options of full-screen or 33%/66% don't quite cut it.