# Windowed Application in Non-Desktop Mode

Tags: windows-8

Ironically enough, on first impression, Windows 8 seems to have gotten rid of the idea of a "window". All the apps are full screen, dialog boxes are virtually forgotten, etc. I know you can go to the Desktop mode on Windows 8 and have an old school windows experience, where you see windows with Minimize and Restore buttons, but are there any windowed applications when you're not in Desktop mode?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/496563/is-there-a-way-to-splitscreen-metro-apps-in-windows-8/496569#496569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in full-screen Windows 8 Metro-UI, the only windowing it supports is [**snapping**](http://www.winsupersite.com/article/windows8/windows-8-feature-focus-snap-142986) of applications, to run 2 at once, in 2 different configurations. App switching can be done using the top left-hand corner.

Other than that, there is **no windowing**.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question or not but if your display supports it you can have apps side by side. Also you can access "minimized" apps by going to the top left corner of the screen.

"The Snap feature in Windows 8 is available only for high resolution monitors where the resolution is more than or equal to 1280 X 768 pixels. If your monitor has a resolution less than 1280 X 768, then the Snap feature is disabled by default."