# Can I wrap Windows 8 desktop apps in Modern UI?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suspend Modern UI app to taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/491846/suspend-modern-ui-app-to-taskbar)
>   [Force a non-metro app to run fullscreen outside the desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/492305/force-a-non-metro-app-to-run-fullscreen-outside-the-desktop)

Is there a way to make regular software in Windows 8 appear as a Modern UI app?  I know I can simply run desktop apps fullscreen, but that doesn't provide the convenience of swiping from the left to switch apps; I can only swipe onto the desktop, from which I have to use the old-style taskbar to switch desktop apps.  Alternatively, is there a way to make Metro apps appear as a regular app on the taskbar?  (This I very much doubt.)  Whatever it is, I just want a little more consistency.

Comment: Most of what you ask has been covered by threads such as [Force a non-metro app to run fullscreen outside the desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/492305/force-a-non-metro-app-to-run-fullscreen-outside-the-desktop), [Windowed Application in Non-Desktop Mode](http://superuser.com/questions/496577/windowed-application-in-non-desktop-mode), [Suspend Modern UI app to taskbar](http://superuser.com/questions/491846/suspend-modern-ui-app-to-taskbar) etc. As for whether a wrapper is possible, that might be a question better suited to StackOverflow. I don't see the advantage really to doing this.

Comment: I wouldn't mind the Windows 8 paradigm so much if there weren't such a sharp edge between Metro and the traditional UI.  I'd just like to push the OS one way or the other.

Comment: Yeah, there's been plenty of discussion about removing Metro and so on. Can't be done without 3rd party apps, and possibly even then not completely. This version of Windows on desktops/non-touch devices at least has a serious case of split personality disorder. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I'm not sure how you could do it though. If the title bar of a Desktop App is removed (including the min./max./close buttons) and it runs in full screen, it would appear to be a Modern UI App. One such example is Google Chrome. If you set it as the default browser and launch it from the Start Screen, it would run as a Modern UI App. I doubt Google officially supports it, instead, I think its Windows that wraps it as a Modern UI App.

Comment: Huh.  Interesting.  Thanks for the tip; I'll have to look into this!