# Is there an app for displaying Live Tiles?

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, modern-ui

Coming from Win7 I was upset that I could no longer use Gadgets. I have a dual-monitor setup and I liked have things like CPU Meter always showing.

I was going to ask if I could just leave the Start Screen open on monitor 2, but that appears to be answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/498711/with-dual-monitors-is-it-possible-to-have-1-screen-in-desktop-mode-and-one-scre).

Is there a Metro app (or Windows program) to which I can add Live Tiles and keep open?

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to put Tiles on the windows 8 desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/502773/is-it-possible-to-put-tiles-on-the-windows-8-desktop)

Comment: Not quite related, as I don't want to put them on the desktop.. No one else knows anything?

Comment: Which is why I said "related", not "duplicate". I guess no-one's come up with an app for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

Old question I know, but someone may find it useful.

Apps that give you Metro live tiles in a sidebar or overlay on New UI or Desktop in Windows 8 or 8.1:

```
1) MetroSidebar
2) Omnimo
```

Apps that give you back Gadgets themselves (as opposed to Metro live tiles):

```
3) 8GadgetPack
4) GadgetsRevived
```

(The last two seem to do the same thing, allow the old DLLs to be installed so Windows re-acquires full Gadget functions and integration, Gadget control panel, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 offers a possiblity to snap a ModernApp to the side of a screen, but it is very delicate and not really user friendly.

I found the [ModernMix Application](http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix/), with that all Modern (Metro) Application can run inside of a normal Window. Very useful.

It's not free, but it's well made and stable.

[image]